# How to delete specific rows that only contains certain numbers?

Tags: r

As an image that I attached, I want to delete rows (ID) that only contains number 9, but not rows that contain other numbers.

Does anyone know how to write r codes to do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of your table (something we can type into R to make that table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on the logical matrix (`df1[-1]==9` - subset of dataset as the first column in 'ID') and check whether it is 0, then keep that row

```
df1[rowSums(df1[-1]==9)==0,]
```

---

If the condition is to keep rows that have numbers other than 9, then as @Rui Barradas, mentioned

```
df1[rowSums(df1[-1] != 9) > 0,]
```

Comment: I wonder if that would do it. Maybe the condition should be `rowSums(df1[-1] != 9) > 0`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  Thanks, it could be the case.  An expected output would have been better in the post